# Installation 16.04 question related to lvmetad

Tags: boot

I erased windows 10 from my new machine and installed ubuntu 16.04, the installation was said to be complete. However, I did not see the guide says to check install third party software, so that is the only difference I had with the installation guide. I have tried Shift right key but nothing shows up. So I cannot boot now. The following shows and it won't proceed. How do I deal with this? Can I reinstall again?
lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that GRUB did not install correctly. To fix that please follow these steps carefully:

1. Insert Ubuntu installation disk (USB or DVD).
2. Boot and select "Try without installing" option
3. Open a terminal when the desktop has loaded
4. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo -s
   add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   apt update
   apt install boot-repair
   boot-repair
   ```
5. Chose recommended option.
6. After a while it will ask you to copy and paste commands into the terminal. Copy and paste all commands given, open a new terminal window, and paste them. You will need to do this at least twice.
7. Once finished, shut down, remove installation medium, and reboot your computer.

This procedure will install GRUB on your computer, the utility that loads the Ubuntu operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Also, I selected using LVM when installing the machine. That may be where the lvmetad comes from.. However, if I just insert the USB drive with ubuntu on it, there is no option to let me select "try without installing". Should I press anything before that shows up?

Comment: Reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 without lvm selected and also check the third party software box. Now the lvmetad message does not appear. It freezes after.. /dev/sda2: clean, 185441/121544704 files, 8571149/486174976 blocks. Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility... Starting Automatically refresh installed snaps...